# A Label with Tap GestureRecognizer inside a ListView custom ViewCell is not working

Tags: listview, xamarin

I have a listview with a custom `ViewCell` which has a `Label` with a `TapGestureRecognizer` that I want to be fired at the *Parent* BindingContext. This view cell is bound to a "Something" viewmodel, the SomeThing viewmodel is a part of SomethingBigger viewmodel.

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell 
{

    #region bindable properties

    public static readonly BindableProperty ToggleCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ToggleCommand), typeof(Command), typeof(CustomViewCell), null);

    public ICommand ToggleCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ToggleCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggleProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion


    public CustomViewCell
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            ColumnSpacing = 3,
            RowSpacing = 0
        };

        //..........
        // adding other elements here
        //..........

        var addLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "+ Add",
            FontSize = 11,
            WidthRequest = 40,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        addLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = ToggleCommand,
            CommandParameter = BindingContext
        });

        grid.Children.Add(addLabel, 7, 1);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(addLabel, 2);

        View = grid;
    }
}
```

`SomethingBiggerViewModel` with a command that should be executed if label is tapped:

```
public class SomethingBiggerViewModel 
{
     public ICommand ToggleCommand { get; set; }

     public SomethingBiggerViewModel() 
     {
          ToggleCommand = new Command<SomethingViewModel>(async (something) => await ExecuteToggleCommand(something));
     }

    async Task ExecuteToggleCommand(SomethingViewModel something)
    {
        await _pageService.DisplayAlert("title", "item clicked " + something.Name, "Cancel");
    }
}
```

and in the page:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            x:Name="linesListView" 
            RowHeight="{Binding LineRowHeight}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}"
            SeparatorColor="#bfbfbf">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:CustomViewCell ToggleCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path=BindingContext.ToggleCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The above compiles, but when I run it, it gives me an error "yet it keeps working" that says "SomethingViewModel" does not have the "ToggleCommand".

How to do this?

Comment: Could you show your complete viewmodel and axml ? `x:Reference ThePage` here you want to bind to the page's viewmodel ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I wasnt to bind to the parent viewmodel (`SomethingBigger`).

Comment: the `ToggleCommand` is defined in `SomethingBiggerViewModel` ,you should binding `SomethingBiggerViewModel`